# LDAP certificate randomly expiring

Tags: java, ssl, ldap, ssl-certificate, spring-ldap

Java 7, Spring Security, running on Linux.

I'm developing a Java application that needs to authenticate users with LDAP over SSL. Instead of installing the certificate in the standard location, I'm contacting the LDAP server when the application starts, downloading a fresh certificate (using InstallCert.java), and saving it to a local file. I have the properties

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path/to/store
```

and

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
```

correctly defined and pointing to where I save the certificate - the certificate is valid; I checked it with keytool.

Everything works fine for a period of time - I can authenticate users with no problem. However, after some time (around 30 to 60 seconds or so) the attempts to authenticate start to fail with:

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I have a loop certificating the same user over and over, so I can reproduce the problem every time.

If I restart my application and download a new certificate, everything works fine again, but after some time, I start to get the same exception.

I'm pretty sure I have a valid certificate: I remove the previous one before starting the application, a new one shows up, and keytool tells me it's valid; the program works for some time, so my code must be correct. I spent the entire day on Google trying to find some clue as to why this is happening, with no luck.

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Application log with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` on:

```
keyStore is : 
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trustStore is: ../resources/secKS
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: <omitted>
  Issuer:  <omitted>
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x127b251800020002f2b7
  Valid from Sat Mar 01 07:16:28 CST 2014 until Sun Mar 01 07:16:28 CST 2015

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1387899859 bytes = { 63, 26, 24, 110, 212, 176, 189, 126, 142, 53, 15, 168, 88, 7, 104, 99, 204, 149, 116, 233, 23, 209, 28, 147, 217, 94, 149, 88 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: pc.example.com]
***
Thread-4, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 183
Thread-4, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 7214
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1387899859 bytes = { 43, 203, 90, 227, 241, 108, 250, 97, 218, 162, 229, 10, 242, 201, 102, 172, 244, 127, 1, 159, 112, 85, 64, 200, 127, 176, 209, 88 }
Session ID:  {239, 31, 0, 0, 50, 39, 125, 41, 69, 122, 153, 226, 211, 8, 67, 220, 191, 105, 65, 238, 228, 237, 177, 199, 140, 18, 237, 199, 169, 242, 23, 209}
Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-2, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
** SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=<omitted>
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 128480787328905034341484558614507757088759660031698956680126704737026971009098243483416647680153867037389802340068271646449681090771848694755692150570797149041184892936137394715909937404525650963377213859810628284412870136267487017282593188331276449067115775494714024533885156245603504553374357102100301531921
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Sat Mar 01 06:40:31 CST 2014,
               To: Sun Mar 01 06:40:31 CST 2015]
  Issuer: CN=<omitted>
  SerialNumber: [    125a3b12 00020002 f2b2]

Certificate Extensions: 10
[1]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.10 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 28 30 26 30 0C 06 0A   2B 06 01 04 01 82 37 14  .(0&0...+.....7.
0010: 02 02 30 0A 06 08 2B 06   01 05 05 07 03 01 30 0A  ..0...+.......0.
0020: 06 08 2B 06 01 05 05 07   03 02                    ..+.......


[2]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.7 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 2F 30 2D 06 25 2B 06   01 04 01 82 37 15 08 BD  ./0-.%+.....7...
0010: C1 4E 81 81 8D 71 84 91   9B 29 85 8F A0 6C 83 C6  .N...q...)...l..
0020: 9E 71 40 82 EF 96 27 82   9F 92 25 02 01 67 02 01  .q@...'...%..g..
0030: 00                                                 .


[3]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: ldap:///<omitted>cACertificate?base?objectClass=certificationAuthority
, 
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: http://<omitted>
, 
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: http://<omitted>
, 
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://<omitted>
]
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: CE 94 DC 6E 73 C2 80 92   13 F2 A1 47 D6 77 42 C4  ...ns......G.wB.
0010: 39 B0 B8 F4                                        9...
]
]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: ldap:///<omited,, URIName: http://<omitted>, URIName: <omitted>]
]]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.1007822.2115313.8670633.10735724.7442289.64.1.402]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
  qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
  qualifier: 0000: 16 2C 68 74 74 70 3A 2F   2F 70 6B 69 64 70 31 2E  .,http://pkidp1.
<omitted>
]]  ]
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.2
  serverAuth
  clientAuth
]

[8]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[9]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: <omitted>
]

[10]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 5C E5 8F AB 06 7C 50 BD   D7 91 69 34 48 8C D2 0E  \.....P...i4H...
0010: 2A D6 5E 20                                        *.^ 
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 54 EB FB 2B 36 D5 23 29   66 09 74 80 DE 94 26 42  T..+6.#)f.t...&B
0010: F3 26 99 D9 BA 5F BC FE   65 F3 5B C5 C1 5F 18 78  .&..._..e.[.._.x
0020: 19 E1 FE 2C 8C 97 66 54   05 D8 A9 B6 FC 41 31 80  ...,..fT.....A1.
0030: 0B EB 39 44 BF 88 C7 8E   3F 6F AB 27 E0 EF C5 C0  ..9D....?o.'....
0040: F5 3F B3 53 56 22 2F 94   51 73 6D 01 31 E5 0C 24  .?.SV"/.Qsm.1..$
0050: C7 35 6D 8C 63 5F 10 BB   42 11 EB 39 D0 92 3B 27  .5m.c_..B..9..;'
0060: 42 DB CB 41 F4 8A F1 D7   25 44 A7 DE 11 B8 E5 EB  B..A....%D......
0070: 29 6D 75 61 09 F5 BE 2F   D1 4D 91 78 C8 9C 34 73  )mua.../.M.x..4s
0080: B8 B6 D4 64 CC 64 4C 50   12 0C A5 5C 66 66 94 DE  ...d.dLP...\ff..
0090: C3 09 BA 75 F5 DE B2 22   73 09 F0 F6 6D 64 25 2F  ...u..."s...md%/
00A0: FB 33 C6 3A C3 8E F2 96   D8 13 EA BD 40 10 50 A8  .3.:........@.P.
00B0: 7B BE 8F 48 43 9A 80 85   A8 5A DB 25 64 B4 5F A1  ...HC....Z.%d._.
00C0: 15 DD 71 AB 20 8C 3F 36   67 7D A0 D5 09 73 02 6C  ..q. .?6g....s.l
00D0: 1C 69 DE 2E A0 07 1C 96   49 71 E8 9A 15 93 0D A0  .i......Iq......
00E0: 27 FC 73 0F 53 17 8B C3   E6 AC 1A 39 15 A2 CC 83  '.s.S......9....
00F0: CE 1F 7D 79 D5 CF BE DD   85 1A 64 1B EF F9 41 9E  ...y......d...A.

]
chain [1] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=<omitted>
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 22359192553251616882525512914135207862945316850625026509586220104340455864279327000337629161502114363440487498639724175623567951470270794891768252994144317953686898150451581587331248901162533312932905859809140387248649026857190124469942099318196674743474482499088660217974341345944208179433864168172021412841174101665154974669658170086712373136041250932220633357002927590609385993765726852902828352147267966342020529750696982039607593091983184202136548479526185053237959817275435129563865352944485076789990784360767974182750619019222278262960413441606680606770005561065163487771275176732178246055288446333467601387131
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Wed Aug 30 03:42:29 CDT 2006,
               To: Tue Aug 30 03:52:29 CDT 2016]
  Issuer: CN=<omitted>
  SerialNumber: [    61ff4ed3 00020000 000a]

Certificate Extensions: 9
[1]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 0C 1E 0A 00 53 00 75   00 62 00 43 00 41        .....S.u.b.C.A


[2]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.1 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 05 02 03 02 00 02                               .......


[3]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.2 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 16 04 14 1E D8 DF 73   2F D9 42 5A 95 2D 90 10  .......s/.BZ.-..
0010: FF 8F 8F C1 1E 68 74 29                            .....ht)


[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 01 4B 94 26 22 E6 F5 D0   92 7F 4B 79 9D 9F A6 8D  .K.&".....Ky....
0010: BE 70 65 F8                                        .pe.
]
]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: <omitted>, URIName: <omitted>, URIName: <omitted>]
]]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.1007822.2115313.8670633.10735724.7442289.64.1.402]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
  qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
  qualifier: <omitted>

]]  ]
]

[8]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]

[9]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: CE 94 DC 6E 73 C2 80 92   13 F2 A1 47 D6 77 42 C4  ...ns......G.wB.
0010: 39 B0 B8 F4                                        9...
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 75 C2 37 CE AD 22 7A B2   82 AA 70 4C 0D 00 4C 36  u.7.."z...pL..L6
0010: 16 A5 CF AE 46 62 F8 46   87 68 B4 02 EA 2D 57 DD  ....Fb.F.h...-W.
0020: F9 BA 80 AA 86 55 9D 0C   80 8B 32 A2 E6 91 81 29  .....U....2....)
0030: 17 63 DF 93 A1 E8 B8 BE   D1 7C E9 09 FD C3 89 F2  .c..............
0040: F5 C3 59 A7 61 EA FE 79   6F BD E1 4B DC 53 14 18  ..Y.a..yo..K.S..
0050: 2B F0 37 95 06 D1 83 86   8F 4B 91 54 66 57 49 5E  +.7......K.TfWI^
0060: 87 D6 56 42 AC E2 AB 65   05 AB 8E 17 5A DD 82 15  ..VB...e....Z...
0070: 7D 41 4B 1D 17 EC 27 6B   5D 9F 90 5D FD A3 9F 89  .AK...'k]..]....
0080: 82 95 04 4A 7C E6 F8 97   BA DC 7C 29 6C F4 96 62  ...J.......)l..b
0090: 61 52 61 CD 30 E4 A3 2D   B9 CE 91 80 66 98 D7 82  aRa.0..-....f...
00A0: D0 96 B1 CB 01 DB 80 21   63 F1 3F 6D 80 5A 07 FC  .......!c.?m.Z..
00B0: 97 BF A5 50 AA AA 30 9A   02 2C 6A 06 EC D4 C0 C5  ...P..0..,j.....
00C0: D3 35 EE 62 E1 FA 9D 3E   08 27 AA FB D8 A9 1D B9  .5.b...>.'......
00D0: 7B A9 4D 90 D8 BD CA 2D   62 8E 87 76 FD FF 9F 6E  ..M....-b..v...n
00E0: 5C 18 45 7F 9E 8E 75 99   D3 AC 03 50 64 D3 6E B6  \.E...u....Pd.n.
00F0: 97 03 50 0D D6 1E 7F B6   BE 4B 16 07 CE C1 A8 77  ..P......K.....w

]
***
%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
Thread-4, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
Thread-4, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
Thread-4, called closeSocket()
Thread-4, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
pool-1-thread-2, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
09:21:07.904 [pool-1-thread-2] ERROR c.m.c.s.c.CachingSecurityServiceImplementation .- Exception thrown while authenticating user [aantena2]
09:21:07.911 [pool-1-thread-2] ERROR c.m.c.s.handlers.SecurityHandler .- Error executing request
....SecurityServiceException: Exception thrown while authenticating user [...]
Caused by: org.springframework.ldap.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: pc.example.com:636; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: pc.example.com:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]
    at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:100) ~[spring-ldap-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.bindAsUser(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:187) ~[spring-security-ldap-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:127) ~[spring-security-ldap-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:80) ~[spring-security-ldap-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.cmd.security.cache.CachingSecurityServiceImplementation.getUser(CachingSecurityServiceImplementation.java:201) ~[security-server-0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: pc.example.com:636
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:218) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2740) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:316) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:193) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:211) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:154) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:84) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:153) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider$ContextFactory.createContext(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:347) ~[spring-security-ldap-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.bindAsUser(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:181) ~[spring-security-ldap-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.run(Connection.java:853) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you run the client with -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake and post the output here? You can abbreviate but I'd like to see all the SSL handshake messages, e.g. ServerHello, Certificate, etc, which are delimited with double-asterisks, and also the certificate chain itself.

Comment: NB There's no evidence here about certificate expiry. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I'll post it on Monday, when I'm back in the office. Last thing I managed to get out of internet research was that the message I get seems to be somewhat related to a timestamp problem.

Comment: I believe the relevant piece is this: ***
%% Invalidated:  [Session-4, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
pool-1-thread-7, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
pool-1-thread-7, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
pool-1-thread-7, called closeSocket()
pool-1-thread-7, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what was wrong - our LDAP installation is actually load balanced; when I start my application, I get a certificate from one of the servers, but next time I try to authenticate a user, there is no guarantee I'll be hitting the same server.

This explains why it works for some time, so if you come across random SSL errors, make sure you are not hitting a load balanced LDAP.